# SQL to pandas JOIN w/AND issue

Tags: sql, pandas, join

**This SQL query**

```sql
SELECT e.*,
first.first_search,
session.session,
session.session_start
FROM tutorial.yammer_events e
JOIN (
    SELECT user_id,
    MIN(occurred_at) AS first_search
    FROM tutorial.yammer_events
    WHERE event_name = 'search_run'
    GROUP BY 1
) first
ON first.user_id = e.user_id
AND first.first_search <= '2014-08-01'
LEFT JOIN (
--... more subqueries
) session
ON session.user_id = e.user_id
AND session.session_start <= e.occurred_at
AND session.session_end >= e.occurred_at
AND session.session_start <= first.first_search + INTERVAL '30 DAY'
WHERE e.event_type = 'engagement'
```

177044 rows × 11 columns

**This is my pandas version**

```
interval_30_day = pd.Timedelta(days = 30)

e = data_frame.copy()
e = e[e['event_type'] == 'engagement']     

session = final.copy()

first = data_frame.copy()
first = first[first['event_name'] == 'search_run']
first = first.groupby('user_id').agg(first_search=('occurred_at', 'min')).reset_index()

e = pd.merge(e, first, on='user_id')
e = e[e['first_search'] <= '2014-08-01']

e = pd.merge(e, session, on='user_id', how='left')
> e = e.join(session.set_index('user_id'), on='user_id', how='left')  > This does the same
e = e[(e['session_start'] <= e['occurred_at']) & 
      (e['session_end'] >= e['occurred_at']) & 
      (e['session_start'] <= e['first_search'] + interval_30_day)] 
      > If I leave this last line out, it ‘kind of’ works
> 134524 rows × 11 columns

e
```

I’m trying to translate(?) this SQL query into pandas, it all works except the last line.
The line does what I am asking it to do… But not what SQL is telling it to do.
SQL is joining e and leaving those rows blank (for columns 'session' and 'session_start') where the query meets the criteria.

My code leaves those rows out, the only way to have the same amount of rows is if
I leave the last line out, but then the columns have data and not blank

Is the JOIN with AND done incorrectly? how to do it otherwise? Thanks in advance.

This is where the query is coming from:
[This is where the code is coming from, I am doing number 5](https://mode.com/sql-tutorial/understanding-search-functionality-answers/)

[This is the full SQL](https://app.mode.com/benn/reports/f5a390533fd3/runs/d2939fc46864/details/queries/95cf5ab66a16)

Edit:
for user_id 13317, take a look at the session column, between 223114 and 223122, session 223176 is an example of the issue I am having
[image: This is what the SQL query shows]
[image: This is what pandas does with the 3 AND's included]
[image: This is the same pandas with only the first 2 AND's]

So the SQL query does not remove this rows, when it joins them, at this section it shows empty cells.
When I do it in pandas with all 3 AND's it instead removes all those rows instead of giving NaN values for those cells (witch is what I am telling it to do), this is because it's done after the merge. How can I solve this? so that the AND's are taken into consideration as the merge is been done?

Comment: Please provide an actual example of what the result looks like vs what you expect.

Comment: Hello Jan, I apologize for not making my post more clear, made some changes and added pictures showing the results I'm getting. Hope it's more clear, Thanks for stoping by.